# Infopath redirection after cancel and submit

Tags: sharepoint-2007, infopath-2007

I have the infopath form, I want to redirect it... There are two buttons, I want when user click on submit, it is redirected to page "a.aspx" and when I clicked on cancel, it is redirected to page "b.aspx".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answers from searching.

There should be no rule on the button.

And then on click event of both buttons, use the httprequest.current.response.redirect method